# Keep div overlay relative to background image regardless of window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to overlay some text over a background image with `background-size: cover`.

Problem here is how do I keep the overlay div at the same position, relative to the background image, regardless of the window's size?

Here's a fiddle to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/resting/2yr0b6v7/

So I want to position the word `eye` over the eye of the cat, regardless of window size.

CSS or JS solutions are both welcomed.

Comment: it will move a little but a quick way that would keep it within that area is using `%` rather than `px` to give it its position

Comment: Have tried `%` but it actually moves a lot out of position. Maybe its impossible to have a div overlay relative to a background image. Seems to me its always relative to the window.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f4yovb09/1/embedded/result/ check that out it stays fairly close to the eye on resizing using the % like i mentioned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** Added js alternative

I was convinced that this could be done with css and almost gave up, but then I remembered the new(ish) css units [vh and vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)....

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmenrd4z/)

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.cat {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/800/400) no-repeat center center / cover;
}
.place-on-eye {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    margin:0;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {    
    .place-on-eye {
        bottom: 50%;
        left: 46.875%;
        margin-bottom: 1.25vw;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {   
    .place-on-eye {
        bottom: 52.5%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -6.25vh;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

So the left eye is at approx 375, 190, and since the image is centered, we will also want to know how far off the center it is, so 25, 10.  Since the image is covering, the size of the image will change based on whether the aspect ratio of the viewport is greater or less than the aspect ratio of the background image.  Knowing this, we can use media queries to position the text.

The image is 2:1, so when the viewport aspect ratio is > 2:1, we know that the width of the image is the width of the viewport, so the left position of the `<p>` should always be 46.867% (375/800). The bottom position is going to be more difficult because the image extends beyond the viewport top and bottom. We know that the image is centered, so first move the `<p>` to the middle, then push it up by 2.5% (10/400) of the height of the image.  We don't know the height of the image, but we do know the image aspect ratio and that the width of the image is equal to the width of the viewport, so 2.5% of the height = 1.25% width.  So we have to move the bottom up by 1.25% width, which we can do by setting `margin-bottom:1.25vw`.  Incidentally, we can do this without `vw` in this case because padding is always calculated relative to the width, so we could have set `padding-bottom:1.25%`, however this won't work in the next case where you have to position the left relative to the height.

The case when the aspect ratio is < 2:1 is analogous.  The height of the image is the height of the viewport, so the bottom position should always be 52.5% (210/400) and the left is calculated similar to above.  Move it over to center, then back it up by 3.125% (25/800) the width of the image, which is equal to 6.25% the height of the image, which is equal to the viewport height, so `margin-left:-6.25vh`.

Hopefully this is correct and helps you out!

**JS Alternative**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbun9c2e/3/)

Here's an alternative that uses js.  It uses some features like forEach and bind that might cause problems depending on how old a browser you need it to work on, but they are easily replaceable. With js you can directly calculate the scaled dimensions of the bg image which makes the positioning easier. Not the most elegant code, but here goes:

```
//elem:     element that has the bg image
//features: array of features to mark on the image
//bgWidth:  intrinsic width of background image
//bgHeight: intrinsic height of background image
function FeatureImage(elem, features, bgWidth, bgHeight) {
    this.ratio = bgWidth / bgHeight; //aspect ratio of bg image
    this.element = elem;
    this.features = features;
    var feature, p;
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        feature = features[i];
        feature.left = feature.x / bgWidth; //percent from the left edge of bg image the feature resides
        feature.bottom = (bgHeight - feature.y) / bgHeight; //percent from bottom edge of bg image that feature resides               
        feature.p = this.createMarker(feature.name);
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.setFeaturePositions.bind(this));
    this.setFeaturePositions(); //initialize the <p> positions
}

FeatureImage.prototype.createMarker = function(name) {
    var p = document.createElement("p"); //the <p> that acts as the feature marker
    p.className = "featureTag";
    p.innerHTML = name;
    this.element.appendChild(p);
    return p
}

FeatureImage.prototype.setFeaturePositions = function () {
    var eratio = this.element.clientWidth / this.element.clientHeight; //calc the current container aspect ratio
    if (eratio > this.ratio) { // width of scaled bg image is equal to width of container
        this.scaledHeight = this.element.clientWidth / this.ratio; // pre calc the scaled height of bg image
        this.scaledDY = (this.scaledHeight - this.element.clientHeight) / 2; // pre calc the amount of the image that is outside the bottom of the container
        this.features.forEach(this.setWide, this); // set the position of each feature marker
    }
    else { // height of scaled bg image is equal to height of container
        this.scaledWidth = this.element.clientHeight * this.ratio; // pre calc the scaled width of bg image
        this.scaledDX = (this.scaledWidth - this.element.clientWidth) / 2; // pre calc the amount of the image that is outside the left of the container
        this.features.forEach(this.setTall, this); // set the position of each feature marker
    }
}

FeatureImage.prototype.setWide = function (feature) {
    feature.p.style.left = feature.left * this.element.clientWidth + "px";
    feature.p.style.bottom = this.scaledHeight * feature.bottom - this.scaledDY + "px"; // calc the pixels above the bottom edge of the image - the amount below the container
}

FeatureImage.prototype.setTall = function (feature) {
    feature.p.style.bottom = feature.bottom * this.element.clientHeight + "px";
    feature.p.style.left = this.scaledWidth * feature.left - this.scaledDX + "px"; // calc the pixels to the right of the left edge of image - the amount left of the container
}

var features = [
    {
        x: 375,
        y: 190,
        name: "right eye"
    },
    {
        x: 495,
        y: 175,
        name: "left eye"
    },
    {
        x: 445,
        y: 255,
        name: "nose"
    },
    {
        x: 260,
        y: 45,
        name: "right ear"
    },
    {
        x: 540,
        y: 20,
        name: "left ear"
    }
];

var x = new FeatureImage(document.getElementsByClassName("cat")[0], features, 800, 400);
```

Comment: Thanks! The fiddle works perfectly and it uses new CSS specs which I like. However I will have to go with the old school method for now.

Comment: **Update** I realise the other solution breaks if the position is not near to center.

Comment: Are there be any `vw` `vh` alternatives? I guess if we can figure out how the background resizes, I think applying the same algorithm should scale the overlay properly with the background image.

Comment: I've added a js version.  With the css version, I think you need the vw/vh because there's no way that I can think of to nudge something horizontally based on a vertical measure.  I might be wrong about that though.  You can nudge vertically based on a horizontal measure using padding, but not the other way around.  I'd be interested to know of anyway to do that in css without vh if anyone reading knows.

Comment: I have added my JS solution borrowing principles from both solutions. But it's not exactly pinpoint accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/resting/jmgp1vgv/) borrowing the principles from the 2 answers. Black dot should overlay at the end of the line. But this solution drifts from actual spot a little in certain ratios.

Maybe someone can improve it?

JS:

```
$(function() {
    function position_spot() {
        w = $(window).width();
        h = $(window).height();
        wR = w/h;

        // Point to place overlay based on 1397x1300 size
        mT = 293;
        mL = -195;

        imgW = 1397;
        imgH = 1300;
        imgR = imgW/imgH;

        tR = mT / imgH; // Top ratio
        lR = mL / imgW; // Left ratio

        wWr = w / imgW; // window width ratio to image
        wHr = h / imgH; // window height ratio to image

        if (wR > imgR) {
            // backgroundimage size
            h = imgH * wWr;
            w = imgW * wWr;
        } else {
            h = imgH * wHr;
            w = imgW * wHr;
        }
        $('.overlay-spot').css({
            'margin-top': h * tR,
            'margin-left': w * lR
        });
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        position_spot();
    });
    position_spot();

});
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out why this wasn't working for a while.  Everything looked right, and I think it is right, except I finally noticed the actual image width is 1379px not 1397px.  That should fix it!

Comment: You're right. It is 1379px. Looks pretty good :). Updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

According to how you set your background image position and size:

```
background-position:center center;
background-size:cover;
```

the center of background image should still be in the center of your screen - that comes in handy as a constant, so just try to do the same with your `p.place-on-eye`

```
.place-on-eye {
    ...
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Right now paragraph's left top corner is in the center of your screen, if you also add width and height properties you can actually pint elements center into the screen's center. So it's like:

```
.place-on-eye {
    ...
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center /* to make sure the text is center according to elements width */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

So now the center of `p.place-on-eye` is in the exact center of your screen, just like the center of your background image. To get it over the cat's eye just offset the left and top margin as needed.

so something like `margin:-27px 0 0 -60px;` should do it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/resting/tvrph7eg/)