# How to recalculate top and left position when using background size cover on background image

Tags: css, less, background-image, responsive, positioning

I'm working on a website with a responsive background image where the size of that background-image is set to cover.

I also have a link with a hover animation which is positioned with top and left parameters on that background-image. Now my problem is that when my screen is resized I should also recalculate the top and left parameters to correctly show my animation.

The animation should be shown on a particular spot of the background-image. When viewed in resolution 1920x1240 the animation is positioned correctly. But when resizing the screen the position is not correct anymore because the image is scaled.

Is there a way to keep the top and left parameters in sync with the scale and how can I achieve that?

Currently I'm having this css for my background image:

```
div.custom-background {
    background: url('../../assets/resized/de-sneeuwkoningin-xxl.jpg') no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-position: center top;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and for my animation I have the following css:

```
.start {
    background: url('../../assets/de maanvallei_beeldmerk_boek.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 130px;
    height: 122px;
    top: 45%;
    left: 7%;

    &:hover {
        filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px blue);
        transition: filter 0.05s linear;
        width: 130px;
        height: 122px;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I made a fiddle to show the problem. The black dot on the forehead should remain on the same place when resizing the html view.

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3x2njkLu/

Comment: the website you attached to your question is blocked by our campus wifi, please provide a minimal reproducible code that replicates your problem

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I made an edit on my post and now included a fiddle with an example

Answer (score 0):

**I'm providing some general tips that may help you, I hope my math isn't much off for what you need.** You may need to adjust it, full implementation will take you a while

**1.** You need to have your image ratio stored `image_ratio = 1920/1240` (~1.548).
**2.** Then you need to specify in what x,y relative points you want in ideal situation (both height and width equal to window size). Ex. `x = x_coord/width=0.5` and `y = y_coord/height=0.3` (50% left, 30% top).
**3.** Now observe how image behaves when scaling - makes next points differ from case to case. *[Now considering current example view]*
**3.1**. If rendered image dimension (x or y) = 100% of window dimension then `dim_offset = 0`
**3.2.** If rendered image dimension != 100% of window dimension then:
**a)** for height: `y_offset = window height - window width / image_ratio` and your new y: `y_adjusted = y + (y_offset) / (height - y_offset)`
**b)** for width: `x_offset = window width - window height * image_ratio` and your new x: `x_adjusted = x (-+) (x_offset) / (width - x_offset)` **!! (-+) depends on left value - if y<50% then minus, if y>50% then plus, when 50% then it stays the same x=x**

**Your left value is `x_adjusted` and top is `y_adjusted`**
Now I would recommend to use JS to accomplish those calculations with:

- `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight`
- `onresize` event - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp
- for css: access style property of element

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I'm a bit confused on how to calculate the rendered image dimension. What do you mean with x or y = 100%? Currently I'm comparing the imageRatio with the cover ratio but that seems not correct

Comment: That 100% of width or height is visible in rendered page (regardless of scale)

Answer (score 0):

This post pointed me in the right direction: [Keep div overlay relative to background image regardless of window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878124/keep-div-overlay-relative-to-background-image-regardless-of-window-size)

I eventually solved my problem with the aspect ratio and css.

Thanks @Krysztof Nowicki for the tips